# Parsing output from paramiko

Tags: python, paramiko

I am using paramiko todo remote SSH

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(hostname, username='root', key_filename='/root/.ssh/mykey.priv')
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('firewall-cmd --state')
print stdout.readlines()
```

i get the output as

```
[u'running\n']
```

how do I parse it to print only as 'running' ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
print(stdout.read().decode('ascii'))
```

I believe this would solve your problem.

Comment: At least it solved someone else`s problem after they (me) stumbled across this two years after.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying paramiko right now and using recv, according documentation here  http://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.1/api/channel.html it will retrun a byte. So what I have done is converting it to string, see bellow

```
myconn = paramiko.SSHClient()
myconn.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
myconn.connect('192.168.15.254', port=22, username='test',
                password='test', look_for_keys=False,
                allow_agent=False)
myshell = myconn.invoke_shell()
myshell.send('show int ATM 0/0/0 | include put rate \n')
time.sleep(1)
output = myshell.recv(65535)
myconn.close()
print(output)
mystr = output.decode(encoding='UTF-8')
print(mystr)
```

Print output will give you this;

```
b'\r\nROUTER#show int ATM 0/0/0 | include put rate \r\n  30 second   input rate 47000 bits/sec, 37 packets/sec\r\n  30 second output rate 38000 bits/sec, 33 packets/sec\r\nROUTER#'
```

Print mystr will give you this;

```
ROUTER#show int ATM 0/0/0 | include put rate 
  30 second input rate 18000 bits/sec, 16 packets/sec
  30 second output rate 15000 bits/sec, 13 packets/sec
ROUTER#
```

I hope this would put you in the right path at least, if it's not too late.